# Using different NIC vendors on a LAN - does it make a difference?

Tags: ethernet, interface

I was reading up on network interface cards and came across this statement:

"Avoid mixing network adapters from different vendors on the
same LAN. Although all may follow a standard, implementation
differences impacts performance."

Is this true, and is the performance impact anything significant?

Comment: Please cite the source of this statement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've never seen a LAN *without* a mix of vendors for the interfaces on it. I'm not even sure that's really possible in a practical sense. Unless you have a router from a vendor that also makes switches and network cards and you don't use devices that can't take expansion cards or dongles.

Comment: If you're looking at documents circa 1980, then that might have some validity. Today, NICs are built into hardware so you have little choice. Everything implements the same decades old standard, so there are very few differences "on the wire" -- yes, bus interfaces and internal processes can result in different line-rate performance but that's rarely a concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason you can't mix network adapters from different vendors on a LAN. They should all be IEEE compliant and tested for interoperability.

You probably can't help but mix hardware vendors since it is unlikely that the switches to which you connect hosts use the same hardware as the hosts.